# Open source virtual machine

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, jit, vm-implementation

I'm looking for an open source virtual machine that's:

- **fast** and **as lightweight as possible**
- supports a minimal set of bytecode (like LLVM IR)
- easily embedable from a C++ application
- Cross platform (Linux, Windows and OS X)
- x86 support

Comment: Hmm, nobody *ever* asks for a slow, heavy and closed-source solution.  Why don't you just use the Java JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why filter out LLVM ? It's [a set of C libraries](http://llvm.org/docs/UsingLibraries.html#descriptions)

I guess it's not as easy to embed than Lua, but LLVM is so great that it would probably overcome the hassle of integrating it. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527467/how-to-embed-llvm), does it help ?

Answer (score 6):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/) is famous for being ridiculously easy to embed in C/C++. Its VM is open source and cross-platform, very small (both exe size and bytecode instruction set) and at the same time quite fast. But its bytecode may be not suitable for your language. [The bytecode format is documented here.](http://luaforge.net/docman/index.php?group_id=83&selected_doc_group_id=102&language_id=1)

Comment: Lua's VM is not general purpose VM but it may work for your custom language if your language and Lua are not too far apart semantically. A short description of Lua's VM is at http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html#OP_MOVE . If you go this way, I suggest you first try to compile your language to Lua source code.

Answer (score 5):

[NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/) is a programming language and a lightweight virtual machine designed as a generic target for compiler writers. [The documentation](http://nekovm.org/doc/vm) makes it seem really easy to embed the VM in a C or C++ application, but it seems the VM API is not yet documented.

Answer (score 2):

Other possible answer : why not output assembler instead ? it's fast and lightweight, and you don't need a VM at all. Since you target x86 only, it could make sense, depending on what you're trying to do.